# PowerShell to executable - go the extra mile or leave it?

Tags: powershell

It seems like it is not all that easy to create an executable from a PowerShell script - do you know if it was ever meant to be an option?

I have found tools like PS2EXE, but still it does not seem like it was meant to be.

I am asking, if it is worth it to go the extra mile or leave it.

Background reason: I have some less technical users that need a smoother workflow.

Comment: it is NOT intended by the PoSh devs. also, from what i can tell, it is NOT really compiled into machine code - it's an EXE wrapper around the script. it still requires that a powershell host be available - and can still be captured when it is running via the usual audit & transcript methods.

Comment: Good comment - thanks

Comment: thanks! [*grin*] it looks like Stefan has shown a way to give your non-technical techs a way to remain non-tecnichal ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: they will fire me if they see that post at work XD

Comment: depends on the security stance AND your intent ... but that sort of thing is well known as one possible way do handle stubbornly non-technical techs. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Bill_Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102693/bill-stewart) kindly noted:

> PowerShell is a shell that contains a powerful scripting language.

Which is perfectly in line with [Microsoft's definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-6) :

> PowerShell is a task-based command-line shell and scripting language built on .NET.

---

Basically, wrapping it in an executable would go beyond its purpose. The nice thing about scripting is, that it's lightweight and task based. And in this case, that you can easily run it on [multiple OS-ses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6).

So, I wouldn't go through the effort creating an exe.

If you want to run it easily, just create a `.bat` or `.cmd` file (if using Windows). On windows, I believe, you can also create a shortcut with command arguments and a little icon.

For Linux you clould use a `.sh`.

Comment: I would reword from "PowerShell is a powerful scripting language" to "PowerShell is a shell that contains a powerful scripting language."